# No puedo acceder a mi variable publica desde otra clase (C# con Unity)

Tags: c#, unity2d, variables-globales

Esta es la clase que crea la variable click (publica)

```
public class DrawLine : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Sprite One;
    public Sprite Two;
    public Sprite Three;
    public Sprite Four;
    public bool click;

    IEnumerator ChangeSprite()
    {
        this.gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = One;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.5f);
        this.gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = Two;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.5f);
        this.gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = Three;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.5f);
        this.gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = Four;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.5f);
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
        {
            click = true;
            StartCoroutine(ChangeSprite());
        }
        else
        {
            click = false;
        }
    }
```

Y esta es la clase que necesita saber si la variable es verdadera o falsa

```
public class Punching : MonoBehaviour
{
    public bool canScale = false;

    void Update()
    {
        #region
        if (transform.localScale.x == 0.7353f)
        {
            canScale = false;
        }
        else if (transform.localScale.x == 0)
        {
            canScale = false;
        }
        else
        {
            canScale = true;
        }
        #endregion
        if (Input.GetMouseButton(0) && canScale && click)
        {
            transform.localScale = new Vector2(transform.localScale.x + 0.1f, 1);

        }
        else if (!Input.GetMouseButton(0) && transform.localScale.x > 0.1168f && !click)
        {
            transform.localScale = new Vector2(transform.localScale.x - 0.01f, 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Me sale un error que dice que el nombre click no existe en el contexto actual, ¿Alguien sabe porque no puedo acceder a esa variable si es publica?

Comment: Creo que primero deberías aprender a programar con objetos y luego ya intentar hacer otras cosas... que una variable sea pública no significa que puedas usarla *mágicamente* en todas partes... sigues necesitando una instancia de la clase que contiene la variable para acceder a ella. Te recomiendo seguir algún tutorial de scripting en unity que hay un montón de ellos y explican este tipo de cosas normalmente. Si no tienes una base de POO decente, no vas a poder avanzar.

Comment: Además en este caso no te valdría con simplemente crear una instancia de la clase... necesitas la instancia concreta que tiene asignado el objeto que utiliza ese script para poder obtener el valor actualizado. Sin más información de cómo tienes montado el proyecto y donde está asignado el script es muy difícil decirte exactamente lo que tienes que hacer. Por cierto, la variable `click` no es una variable "global"... como mucho podrías hacerla estática y así si podrías acceder desde fuera, pero creo que eso más bien sería un antipattern y acabaría dando más problemas de los que solucionaría.

Comment: Tiene NameSpace? con `using NombreNameSpace.DrawLine;` podrías acceder

Answer (score 1):

Porque en tu clase `Punching` no estás haciendo ninguna referencia a la clase `DrawLine`.

C# es un lenguaje [orientado a objetos](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programaci%C3%B3n_orientada_a_objetos), por lo tanto, no admite variables globales. Para poder acceder al valor de `click` necesitas, en primer lugar, exponerla en [una propiedad](https://www-w3schools-com.translate.goog/cs/cs_properties.php?_x_tr_sl=en&_x_tr_tl=es&_x_tr_hl=es-419&_x_tr_pto=wapp) y asegurarte de tener un valor inicial, tal que así:

```
public class DrawLine : MonoBehaviour
{
    ...
    private bool click = false; // Las variables son privadas, las propiedades públicas
    ...

    public void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
        {
            Click = true; // No cambias la variable, sino la propiedad
            StartCoroutine(ChangeSprite());
        }
        else
        {
            Click = false; // No cambias la variable, sino la propiedad
        }
    }

    public bool Click
    {
        get => click;
        set
        {
            if (value != click)
                click = value;
        }
    }

    // Alternativamente puedes eliminar la *variable* click y usar esta propiedad:
    public bool Click { get; set; } = false;
}
```

En segundo lugar, debes responder a la pregunta **¿necesito instanciar la clase `DrawLine`?** Si la respuesta es *SÍ*, entonces necesitas crear tu variable y acceder a su propiedad:

```
public class Punching : MonoBehaviour
{
    public bool canScale = false;
    private DrawLine drawLine = new DrawLine();

    void Update()
    {
        ...
        if (Input.GetMouseButton(0) && canScale && drawLine.Click)
        {
            transform.localScale = new Vector2(transform.localScale.x + 0.1f, 1);

        }
        else if (!Input.GetMouseButton(0) && transform.localScale.x > 0.1168f && !drawLine.Click)
        {
            transform.localScale = new Vector2(transform.localScale.x - 0.01f, 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Si la respuesta es *NO*, entonces necesitas declarar la propiedad como *estática* y acceder al miembro de clase:

```
public static bool Click { get; set; } = false;
```

```
public class Punching : MonoBehaviour
{
    public bool canScale = false;

    void Update()
    {
        ...
        if (Input.GetMouseButton(0) && canScale && DrawLine.Click)
        {
            transform.localScale = new Vector2(transform.localScale.x + 0.1f, 1);

        }
        else if (!Input.GetMouseButton(0) && transform.localScale.x > 0.1168f && !DrawLine.Click)
        {
            transform.localScale = new Vector2(transform.localScale.x - 0.01f, 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Sé que te serán confusos algunos términos, pero es importante que entiendas qué es la programación **orientada a objetos** antes de querer escribir programas complejos... o juegos.